Laravel SMTP mail driver configuration/timeouts
The official Laravel's documentation is lacking details, so I'm asking here.
We're using Laravel v10 with SMTP mail server (Mailgun) and have rather frequent issue of connection being reset. These are exact error messages:
Expected response code "250" but got empty code.
fgets(): SSL: Connection reset by peer

These two errors do not appear at the same time, but they are rather frequent. I would say that about 99% of emails are delivered, while 1% fails with one of these two messages.
Do note that all emails are sent using Queue, not directly.
After discussing with Mailgun support, this is their response:

From our backend, we can see that in the course of your sending, your connection is going idle and eventually causes a timeout with our SMTP server, and stalls the queue you've created. I think when you're getting those errors, it's happening when the connection is terminated so you're receiving back such errors like the empty response code you saw on the 250s and the Connection reset by peer.

How can I change my configuration so that it would connect per each email? Or how can I set the time it can idle, but then it must re-connect? I noticed timeout option in config/mail.php file, but there's no description of what it does, how it's used and what parameter does it accepts (miliseconds, seconds, minutes, ...).
This is my current configuration:
    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
    ],

